# i hava java swing code,and it is been sucessfully compied ,but the swing components are not displayed on the screen why?

Tags: java, swing

My java swing components are not displayed on the frame. Since it is been compiled without any errors.

I have tried all the possible solutions upto my knowledge but I don't find my problem is solved.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us how we can copy, paste and run code in an image? You will want to create and post a [mcve] as code-formatted text with your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"Since it is been compiled without any errors."* You seem to have the misconception that compiled code will work. It ..doesn't work that way. Compilation does merely some basic checks. There are then a lot of run-time errors that code might experience. The fact that you have not worked that out in command line apps. suggests you should leave GUI programming (an advanced task) aside until more used to debugging.

Comment: Could anyone is able to read the code.

Comment: Start with Swing basics. For example [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). You can look at other parts of the tutorial as well. There are all kinds of examples for you to download and look at So start with a working example and make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
package swingplayground;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author owner
 */
public class SwingPlayground {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Login");
        JLabel uname = new JLabel("User Name");
        JLabel pswd = new JLabel("Password");
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField password= new JPasswordField();

        Container main = jf.getContentPane();
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
        JPanel upane = new JPanel();
        upane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel passpane = new JPanel();
        passpane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        upane.add(uname);
        upane.add(username);

        passpane.add(pswd);
        passpane.add(password);

        main.add(upane);
        main.add(passpane);

        jf.setSize(1024, 728);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Instead of:

```
upane.add(main);
passpane.add(main);
```

you need to say:

```
main.add(upane);
main.add(passpane);
```